# keeping the selection "permanent" in the UITableView cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I seem to be having a problem in my UITableView clicking behaviour. I'm using a Tree to create a hiearchy of tableviews.

My problem arises when I enter the following screen   ( I produced some screenshots to clarify ).

**1)**
When I enter this screen

http://img129.imageshack.us/img129/4050/samplec.png

I can go to my next tableview by clicking on my info button below( second from the left)( **so not by clicking on the cell**).
This works. It will go to the tableview associated with the previous row.

Here is where my "problem"  starts. As soon as I click outside my current tableview , for instance on the empty cell below or if I click the same cell and drag it a bit, 
then my cell will become unselected.

**2)** 
As you can see in the image below.

http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/5930/sample3i.png

I do not want this to happen. I want my cell despite the fact that I'm clicking around to stay selected. Is there a way to realize this?

Comment: A word of caution: Applications have been rejected in the past for similar selection behaviour. Persistent selection without an action **does** break the normal UI convention on iPhone, so think long & hard before going with such.

Comment: retainCount is correct. Do not use a highlight to show selection. Rather, use an accessory view, like a checkmark.

Comment: @retainCount, I believe with 3.0 OS, the restriction on not keeping the tableview cell highlighted) has been lifted.

Comment: Jordan, do you have a link for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a variable, when user selects a cell, store the value of cell in to variable.

Now when User clicks info button, you can do whatever you required as value is stored in variable.

Best of luck.